# Remove the last days from the previous month datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I have two calendars and I would like to use them without displaying the last days of the previous month.
How can I get rid of the extra row? I looked into Datepicker's API, but I couldn't find anything that works.

You can get a better view of the probleme here:
[image: How Datepicker display the months]

I need them to have the same height.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding last days from previous month or next month would not make the height same for these calendars, you need to do some css trick for this.

But if you really need to hide these you can try skipping the events in the `eventRender()` method:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)
{
   if(event.start.getMonth() !== view.start.getMonth()) { return false; }
}
```

Comment: So there isn't a solution to fix somehow the last extra row which appears on some months?

Comment: actually yes... you need to change start day of week accordingly. but it needs some good algo to implement.